# Facebook asks for domain should not contain protocol information

Tags: facebook

I am getting error while verifying an app ID and app secret code...

Error App Domains: http://mayihelpyou.oodus.com should not contain protocol information.

not sure what this error is and how to resolve.... plz help

Answer (score 2):

they ask to delete http:// protocol 
so use your simple domain

```
mayihelpyou.oodus.com
```

Comment: Thanx this resolves the problem.... actually they were asking for the protocol at website url and I have mistakenly placed it at app domains... though thanz alpha... you are too quick...